# Loading new files using Pig LOAD statement

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I wanted to load data from HDFS to HBSE table sing PIG script.

I have hadfs folder structure as below:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user supergroup   63 2014-05-15 20:28 dataparse/good/goodrec_051520142028
-rw-r--r--  1 user supergroup   72 2014-05-15 20:30 dataparse/good/goodrec_051520142030
-rw-r--r--  1 user supergroup   110 2014-05-15 20:32 dataparse/good/goodrec_051520142032
```

In the above all filenames are attached with the timestamp.

Below is my PIG script to load from HDFS to HBASE:

```
G = LOAD '/user/user/dataparse/good/' USING PigStorage(',') as (c1:chararray, c2:chararray,c3:chararray,c4:chararray,c5:chararray);
STORE G INTO 'hbase://test' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('t1:name t1:state t1:phone_no t1:gender');
```

The script is working fine and the data from all the 3 files are written to the Hbase "**test**" table.

Suppose after some time if some more files comes to HDFS  with the same structure and when i run the pig script  it will LOAD all the files in the "**good**" directory along with the already read file. So how can i load only those files which are new files. Already loaded files should not be loaded again into my HBASE table.

How can i do this?

Thanks,
Sapthashree

Comment: Any updates on the above post?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few options here.

**Using globs**

- Using a shell script pick up the "new" files, Use the glob feature so
  that multiple files can be fed into the script. A related use case is
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515481/pig-latin-load-multiple-files-from-a-date-range-part-of-the-directory-structur?rq=1)
- If the files have a date and timestamp in the filename then you can
  use globs directly, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630584/load-multiple-files-in-pig) to inspiration

**Using big guns**

- If using globs is failing you, then you need to bring out the big
  guns, use a custom load function put in the logic to identify "new
  files" in it and you should be good to go. Details [here](http://shrikantbang.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/apache-pig-custom-load-function-2/)

Comment: Hi,I gone through the link you suggested where glob example is explained. But using glob we can provide the pattern to read the specific files in the directory. If if i have new files coming into the directory and each time do i need to change the glob pattern ?I wanted a pattern such a way that each time when the new file is added, only those new files should be read not the old files.How this can be done using glob or other alternative?

Comment: You try using a glob pattern, which is based on the system time or the like. So if your files are named based on date and timestamp and if your glob is also based on date and timestamp, it should work

Answer (score 0):

you need to have some scheduling mechanism where pig job runs time to time. So, in this process you can only process the files which are not processed earlier by keep traking the timestamp and file names or any other field.

See here for more information [Execute Pig from within Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376261/execute-pig-from-within-java-application)